# Does anyone know why this is infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
for (var i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {

    [arr[i], arr[i+1]] = [arr[i+1], arr[i]]
    
}

console.log(arr);
```

I have no idea why this is an infinite loop..

Comment: Think about what setting `arr[i+1]` does when `i` is on the last element.

Comment: Tag your question with a programming language, that's a lot more informative than tagging it with `loops`.

Comment: @tkasul So the codition that I give to for loop which is 'i < arr.length' doesn't stop it looping ? If I understand you right do I need to do [arr[i-1], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[i-1]]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing this will give you a sense of what happens.

```js
async function inifiniteLoop() {
  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  for (var i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {
    [arr[i], arr[i + 1]] = [arr[i + 1], arr[i]];
    console.log(arr);
    console.log(`i: ${i}; arr.length: ${arr.length}`);
    await sleep(2000);
  }
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

(async () => await inifiniteLoop())();
```

While you would get an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception in Java and many other languages this works in JavaScript.

```js
const array = [34]
console.log(array)
array[3] = 23
console.log(array)
```